# am confused on how to do the gets and sets method

Tags: java

Create gets and sets methods:

`getStudentName()` and `setstudentName()`

`getStudentNumber()` and `setStudentNumber()`
I am confused on what to put in the `public void printGrades()` and `printAverage()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class studentGrader
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String studentName;
    private String studentNumber;
    private String[] testNames;
    private int[] testGrades;
    private int currentTestPointer;
    private int maxTestCount = 10;
    private int averageGrade;
    private int testScore;
    public studentGrader(String studentNameL,String studentNumberL)
    {
        studentName = studentNameL;
        studentNumber = studentNumberL;
        testNames = new String[maxTestCount];
        testGrades = new int[maxTestCount];
        currentTestPointer = 0;
        averageGrade = 0;
    }

    public void addTest(String testName, int testScore)
    {
        testNames[currentTestPointer] = testName;
    }  
    public void printGrades()
    {
    }
    public void printAverage()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Most Getters are very simple. 
//The goal is to simply return some variable that is privately stored in a class
//Notice that the variable "studentName" is of type "String" and the method is returning a type "String"
public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

//Most Setters are the same as getters, except they set the variable instead
//This method takes in a parameter(in this case "name") and then sets the desired variable to given parameter
public void setstudentName(String name) {
    studentName = name;
}
```

The getStudentNumber and setStudentNumber are the same and I'll leave that left undone as a mental exercise.

```
//This is an example of how to print something
public void printAverage() {
    //There may be additional logic in here to determine the correct average grade
    system.out.print(averageGrade);
}
```

Comment: If this solution solves your question please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules from Java code style (that not flow to error, but they are used by everyone) along with some JVM defaults:

1. Class name should be in camel-case: `class studentGrader` - `class StudentGrader`
2. `Scanner` class is used to work with inbound data (console, files, ets); this is not a data holder. Should be removed from the class and used as local variable in method.
3. In constructor (usually), same name for local properties and method parameters should be used. To get access to the local properties, do use `this`: `this.studentName = studentName`
4. Arrays `testNames` and `testGrades` are objects with know size. So you should declare it in the class definition and make it `final` (reference is `final`, but not array's content): `private final String[] testNames = new String[10];` and `private final int[] testGrades = new int[10];`
5. Class local parameters are initialized to the default values. For `int` it is a `0`. So no need to do it in the constructor for `currentTestPointer` and `averageGrade`
6. `void addTest(String testName, int testScore)`, in your current increment `currentTestPointer` and check for arrays out of bound (not more than 10) (I think, it is better to use `Map`)
7. `averageGrade` should be double (I think): private double averageGrade;``

Finally, your class could look like this:

```
public class StudentGrader {

    private static final int MAX_TEST_AMOUNT = 10;

    private String studentName;
    private String studentNumber;
    private final String[] testNames = new String[MAX_TEST_AMOUNT];
    private final int[] testGrades = new int[MAX_TEST_AMOUNT];
    private int currentTestPointer;
    private double averageGrade;
    private int testScore;

    public StudentGrader(String studentName, String studentNumber) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public void addTest(String testName, int testScore) {
        if (currentTestPointer < MAX_TEST_AMOUNT) {
            testNames[currentTestPointer] = testName;
            testGrades[currentTestPointer] = testScore;
            currentTestPointer++;
        }
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public void printGrades() {
        // <testName>: <testGrade>
        for (int i = 0; i < currentTestPointer; i++)
            System.out.println(testNames[i] + ": " + testGrades[i]);
    }

    public void printAverage() {
        averageGrade = 0;

        if (currentTestPointer > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentTestPointer; i++)
                averageGrade += testGrades[i];

            averageGrade /= currentTestPointer;
        }

        System.out.println(averageGrade);
    }
}
```